# How to stop the default behavior of find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

When I query

```
Product.find('12aaaa')
```

I expect it to return nil.
But rails is returning me with `Product.find(12)`
how can I stop this behavior?

p.s: Please don't suggest me to convert my id column to string,
I am obviously not gonna do that, it is indexed and is set to auto increment.
And I don't feel converting id to string is a good idea as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect it to return nil

[*find*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) excepts an *id* or *list of ids*, or *an array of ids* as arguments. So when *string arguments* such as `'12aaaa'` are passed, `find` **coerces** them using `to_i` unless if the datatype of `id` is a `string`.

So

```
Product.find('12aaaa') #'12aaaa'.to_i = 12
```

will become

```
Product.find(12)
```

> How can I stop this behavior?

You can't, as this a *default behavior*. And I **don't recommend** changing the default behavior with any sort of *monkey-patching*.

**Note:**

`find` **doesn't return nil** when a record is not found. Instead it raises a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. Whereas `find_by` returns `nil`

Comment: "find coerces them using to_i" - not when id column is of string type.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Totally agree with that :)